# EtherCAT with ROS Melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I have seen that the SOEM package is available for Indigo, Kinetic and the Lunar versions, but not for Melodic yet. I am currently using the git files to get it working but, my question is, is there any plan to have it also in Melodic? That could be useful.

Thanks in advance,

Txema

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303570/ethercat-with-ros-melodic/) by [Txema84](https://answers.ros.org/users/37558/txema84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

soem has been released by Ruben Smits, not by any of the core ROS maintainers.
There is already [an issue targeting the same question](https://github.com/smits/soem/issues/13), but all in all, the repo there is pretty inactive.

It could be released by someone else, but that one would have to take over maintainership as well, so this is something that could only work on a community effort.

It would be important to make sure, though, that Ruben does not plan on releasing later, or one might run into troubles...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-17**:
FYI, I've actually taken over maintainership of this package and just released into meldoic...

**Comment by [zhivko](https://answers.ros.org/users/51812/zhivko/) on 2020-02-16**:
Great!! - I will try it.